# How to restore configuration data for a single iPhone app from iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

iPhoneX, iOS 16.1.2 (and a Mac computer).
Config for one application seems to be broken.

How could config for that single application be restored from iCloud backup without affecting anything else on the phone?
The restore would have to happen to the phone, just extracting some files would not be sufficient.

Comment: iCloud backup is designed to be "the whole iPhone" so there is no way to restore just the settings for one app. You could try iMazing or IExplore and see if they can restore the settings for just one app.

Comment: Thanks, was looking at various apps, but for the most part, the free version does not do anything useful, and some of them look real dodgy, too.